# deploying Node on heroku error after build successful

Tags: node.js, heroku

i have been trying to deploy a node.js app on heroku. the app run successfully on local machine and it build successful with git heroku push master. but when try to open the app on heroku, it shows a blank page and on the console i got the bellow error.
so i my app i uses owlcarousel, and react -carousel. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it locally with `NODE_ENV=production node index.js` to see if you can reproduce the error like that. Check the `.gitignore` to see if you are not leaving out some important files. Check the `package.json` If a module that is included in the `package.json` is missing from the build or the production app, it may have been removed by Heroku during pruning. And also, in order to create a smaller slug size for apps, the `buildpack` will prune out the `devDependencies` from the `package.json` at the end of the build, so that the slug will only include the dependencies that are listed at runtime. If there is a dependency that is in the `devDependencies` that is needed after the prune occurs, move the dependency to `dependencies`, so it is not removed. Look here for more info, [troubleshooting Node.js deployment on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys).

Comment: thanks @perthos, it seems i have overcome that, that particular error has gone, but now the page is show a blank page and when i check the console, i got some error which are "Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js ...." , "Refused to apply style from 'http...", i am attaching the error screenshot to the question now.

Comment: Glad to help, as for this new problem. Try creating, if you haven't already, a `public` folder where you will store all needed scripts and styles. Then add this to your `express` setup `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`.

Comment: thanks man, i added that and im still getting the same error

Comment: Post the new problem as a new question, maybe someone knows what is the solution.